# How do I get access to rails session in the console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-5

Say I have copied the string for a cookie from a browser request.

```
_some_session=RXF6SVF5RHdV...
```

I want to open the rails console and paste something like

```
> session[RXF6SVF5RHdV...]
```

To retrieve the decrypted data from the session. If this is possible, how do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible, here is more detailed way, open your rails console to try this:

```
content = 'BAh7CEkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRkkiJTgwZGFiNzhiYWZmYTc3NjU1ZmVmMGUxM2EzYmEyMDhhBjsAVEkiFGdpdGh1Yl91c2VybmFtZQY7AEZJIhJuZWVyYWpkb3RuYW1lBjsARkkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMU1KTCs2dXVnRFo2R2NTdG5Kb3E2dm5BclZYRGJGbjJ1TXZEU0swamxyWU09BjsARg%3D%3D--b5bcce534ceab56616d4a215246e9eb1fc9984a4'
```

assuming content is your session cookie,

When the content is written to cookie then it is escaped. So first we need to unescape it.

```
> unescaped_content = URI.unescape(content)
=> "BAh7CEkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRkkiJTgwZGFiNzhiYWZmYTc3NjU1ZmVmMGUxM2EzYmEyMDhhBjsAVEkiFGdpdGh1Yl91c2VybmFtZQY7AEZJIhJuZWVyYWpkb3RuYW1lBjsARkkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMU1KTCs2dXVnRFo2R2NTdG5Kb3E2dm5BclZYRGJGbjJ1TXZEU0swamxyWU09BjsARg==--b5bcce534ceab56616d4a215246e9eb1fc9984a4"
```

Notice that towards the end unescaped_content has -- . That is a separation marker. The value before -- is the real payload. The value after -- is digest of data.

```
> data, digest = unescaped_content.split('--')
=> ["BAh7CEkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRkkiJTgwZGFiNzhiYWZmYTc3NjU1ZmVmMGUxM2EzYmEyMDhhBj  VEkiFGdpdGh1Yl91c2VybmFtZQY7AEZJIhJuZWVyYWpkb3RuYW1lBjsARkkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMU1KTCs2dXVnRFo2R
2NTdG5Kb3E2dm5BclZYRGJ
GbjJ1TXZEU0swamxyWU09BjsARg==", "b5bcce534ceab56616d4a215246e9eb1fc9984a4"]

The data is Base64 encoded. So let’s unecode it.
> Marshal.load(::Base64.decode64(data))
=> {"session_id"=>"80dab78baffa77655fef0e13a3ba208a",
    "github_username"=>"manoj910",
    "_csrf_token"=>"MJL+6uugDZ6GcStnJoq6vnArVXDbFn2uMvDSK0jlrYM="}
So we are able to get the data that is stored in cookie.
```

Comment: @P0lska you forgot to upvote by clicking up arrow in the answer :)

Comment: Didn't work for me. There is no "--" in my session cookie. I get the error "TypeError (incompatible marshal file format (can't be read))"

Comment: Turns out I was using ActiveRecord store so I had to look it up based on the session ID

Comment: In Ruby 3.1.4 I had to do `unescaped_content = URI::DEFAULT_PARSER.unescape(content)` because `URI.unescape` gives `NoMethodError: undefined method `unescape' for URI:Module`

Comment: And then `Marshal.load` failed with `<internal:marshal>:34:in \`load': incompatible marshal file format (can't be read) (TypeError)\n format version 4.8 required; 107.109 given`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an answer that works for non-cookie-based sessions too. I.e. normally all that you would save in the cookie is the session ID. Now given the session ID you can lookup the session data independently from the used session store (file, cache, ActiveRecord) like this:

```
def lookup_session_data(session_id)
  session_store = Rails.application.config.session_store.new nil, {}
  _id, data = session_store.find_session({}, Rack::Session::SessionId.new(session_id))

  data if data.present?
end

session_id = "..."
lookup_session_data session_id
```

Comment: Not working for CookieStore (rails default).